# Initialising boost::array after declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, c++03

We can initialise a boost or std::array using the following syntax:

```
array<int,5> b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

This is fine if 'b' is a local variable. How about if 'b' is a class member?

```
b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // Error: expected an expression
b = array<int,5>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // Error: type name is not allowed 
b = array<int,5>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}); // Error: expected an expression
b = array<int,5>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // Error: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "array<int, 5>"
```

Do you really have to do this:

```
array<int,5> c = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

b = c;
```

Which seems a little wasteful as it creates 'c', initialises it, and then copies it into b before destroying 'c'.

Comment: State the version of the compiler.

Comment: I don't think the version of the compiler will help, but it supports C++ 2003 standard.

Comment: So you use c++03 (which is different than c++0x) ?

Comment: Maybe I don't know what c++0x actually is, but yes, it's 2003. All these different versions confuse me.

Comment: `c++0x` is a place-holder for "the next standard" before C++11 got ratified. So is an incomplete implementation of the best interpretation of the future standard as it was being developed. So the compiler version does actually matter, because the larger the version, the closer it comes to C++11.

Comment: Ok, the compiler version number is 7.1, which was released at the end of February this year, the maximum version of C++ it supports is still 2003 however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create them as in your question which will create a temporary on the stack and then copy it across to your instance (which may be a little wasteful), or you can use static variables and an initialisation list in which any compiler worth its salt will just initialise the appropriate members of the class:

```
class temp
{
   public:
   temp():b(b_default) {}
   array<int, 5> b;
   static array<int, 5> b_default;
};
array<int, 5> temp::b_default = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

This way is probably the 'cleanest' way however: (again, a single copy for all decent compilers)

```
class temp
{
   public:
   temp() 
   {
    static const array<int, 5> b_default = {1,2,3,4,5};

    b = b_default;
   }
   array<int, 5> b;
   static const array<int, 5> b_default;
};
```

Comment: You are still initializing *then* assigning to the data member. There's no need for that.

Comment: It generates exactly the same code as your answer, but without having to have a method for every single array I need to initialise (just an extra variable that gets optimised away), so I'd say it was the cleanest way here. If you have a better method, please post it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also initialize data members at the point of declaration:

```
struct Foo
{
  array<int,5> b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
};
```

Alternatively, you can also use the constructor initialization list

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo() : b{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} {}
  array<int,5> b;
};
```

Note, all your statements involving `b = X` are not *initializations*, they are *assignments*.

**Edit**:
This kind of initialization is not possible in C++03, but you could achieve something similar by calling a function that returns an suitable initialized array:

```
boost::array<int, 5> make_array()
{
  // trivial example, but you can do more complicated stuff here
  boost::array<int, 5> a = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
  return a;
}
```

then

```
Foo() : b(make_array()) {}
```

Comment: Sorry, the variable is in the class and the compiler doesn't support data initialisation, so I have to do the init in the constructor. I guess they are assignments though, yes.

Comment: @Steve The variable is in the class here too. Anyway, the above is valid C++11. If you can't use C++11 you should state that clearly in the question.

Comment: I clearly said "I'm not using C++11". I've now removed that and added the tag "C++03" instead.

Comment: @Steve Well, you managed to get two people to give you C++11 answers, so obviously there was some confusion with the tags and/or the question.

Comment: Indeed. So are you saying it's impossible in C++03 ? If not, adding this to your question will get it accepted :)

Comment: @Steve It isn't as simple, but it is (kind of) possible. I added something.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following:

```
struct S
{
  std::array<int, 5> b = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
};
```

Note the double `{`

Comment: The double braces shouldn't be required. Brace elision should allow single braces.

Comment: Error: data initialization is not allowed.

Comment: @juanchopanza: gcc 4.8.1 requires it : http://ideone.com/vAv4Fh ... Whereas I got a warning with clang 3.4

Comment: @Jarod42 I think it is wrong to require it. But this is an unclear aspect of the C++11 standard, which may have been fixed for C++14.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I solve this kind of problem by creating my own initialization functions. Here, with preprocessor (in order to stay compatible with C++03), but it can be done with variadic templates (>= c++11).

```
#define NMAX_MAKE_ARRAY_PARAMETERS 30
#define MAKE_ARRAY_EDIT(z, n, data) \
  a__[n] = x__ ## n;
#define MAKE_ARRAY_DEFINITION(z, n, data) \
  template <typename T> boost::array<T,n> make_array(BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n, const T& x__)) \
  { \
    boost::array<T,n> a__; \
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n, MAKE_ARRAY_EDIT, 0) \
    return a__; \
  }
#define MAKE_ARRAY_DEFINITIONS(n) \
  BOOST_PP_REPEAT(BOOST_PP_INC(n), MAKE_ARRAY_DEFINITION, 0)
MAKE_ARRAY_DEFINITIONS(NMAX_MAKE_ARRAY_PARAMETERS)
```

With this code included, I can easily create arrays having size between 0 and 30 :

```
boost::array<double,5> a = make_array<double>(1.0, 2.2, 3.4, 4.6, 5.8);
a = make_array<double>(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4);
```